# 4 second delay between each request in Jmeter 5.3

Tags: jmeter, delay, jmeter-5.0

I recently installed Jmeter 5.3, and while running a test, i noticed that each request has a delay of 4 seconds, even though I do not have an delay thread anywhere. If i run the same test in Jmeter 5.2.1, I do not see any delay, and every request works fine.

Any inputs?

Comment: You can send your sample test plan with delay to jmeter mailing list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into [JMeter Changelog](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) there were only 2 non-cosmetic changes between versions 5.2.1 and 5.3:

1. Changing default value of the [`httpclient4.time_to_live` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#httpclient4) from 2 seconds to 1 minute in order to be in line with modern browsers default settings, can be reverted via *user.properties* file
2. Upgrading [Groovy library](http://groovy-lang.org/) to version 3 from version 2, can be reverted by removing all `grooovy-xxxx.jar` libraries from "lib" folder of your JMeter installation and replacing them with [groovy-all-2.4.16.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.16/groovy-all-2.4.16.jar)

None of the changes gives 4 second delay between requests.

More information: [What's New in JMeter 5.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-5.3)

If you need to understand what your threads are doing during this 4 seconds delay time frame - take a [thread dump](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump), it can be done even via JMeter GUI

[image]

Comment: Thank you Dimitri. Let me do both the things:
1. Downgrade all groovy files
2. Take a thread dump

Comment: Thank you once again. Here is what i did:
1. Remove all existing groovy files from lib
2. Copy groovy-all-2.4.16.jar from 5.2.1 to 5.3
3. Re-run 

This works. So its the new groovy that seems to be adding this delay for whatever reason. Thanks again.